# Where can I find complete details of _grokparsefailure

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am using Docker and ELK stack. And using date and grok filters to parse a custom logs.

During this experiment I found _grokparsefailure in the Kibana document.

I am trying to investigate more details, why Grok failed parsing the string.

I tried to use Logstash docker logs. But could not find any trace.

Is there any way to see the reasons behind grok parsing errors

Thanks, Raghu

Answer (score -1):

Copy the message for the failed parsing and head to the [Grok Debugger in the Dev Tools](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-grokdebugger.html) with your grok pattern. There you can debug what as going wrong.